# Can we harness cosmic rays to build particle collider?

Tags: physics

Will we ever be able to harness high energy cosmic rays 
for researching, discovering and proving the existence 
of sub-atomic (leptons, quarks) particles?

Today, the 27km circumference circular LHC at CERN 
produces up to 6.5 TeV by accelerating protons in a 
controlled, artificial, cold, near vacuum conditions.
So, they have found the Higgs Boson- but what's next?

I know that in order to create and prove the other sub 
atomic particles in the zoo, researchers will need much 
higher energies that may be achieved by using ELHC
with a circumference as large as the Earth's 
orbit around the Sun.

So, how about this crazy idea:
ELHC (Exteremely Large Hardon Collider [which I've just 
invented...]) can use the coldness and emptiness of 
space, harness cosmic rays, and accelerate them from 
one end of the earth, AROUND THE SUN to a detector 
assembly on the other side of the globe.
Instead of digging a circular tunnel, we may use the 
gravitational pull of the Sun to bend the particles 
path from the source back to the detector assembly on 
the other side of the earth. For example, take one 
point in the USA (say, northeast of Bangor Maine) and 
the other side in China (say, Darigonga Mongolia).

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding Arn! This site is for questions about creating fictional worlds and at the moment it isn't obvious that your question is for this purpose. To make it less likely to be closed, you can [edit your question to improve it](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/89682/edit). If you haven't already, please [take the tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and check out [the help centre](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Sorry, but I think your understanding of accelerating particles, gravitationnal pull and orbital mechanics is quite confused. There are many wrong assumptions on these matters in your post but I'm not sure where to start. So I'd say no you can't, but this is open to elaboration on a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple place to start would be looking at [escape velocities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity). These are the velocities required for an object (of any mass) to escape the gravitational influence of a particular massive body.

For the sun, that escape velocity is a paltry 617.5 km/s. The current Large Hadron Collider accelerates protons to [0.999999990 c](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider) or about 299,792 km/s. Particles at that speed would still be deflected by the Sun, but would be very far from being able to pull a 180.

To obtain this high speed, the particles would need something other than gravity to swing them around the sun. Solely on this basis, that idea is impossible.

Other folks could probably go more in depth about the other issues involved with having a sender/detector on Earth (atmospheric/magnetic interference), orbital planning, and probably a few more inaccurate assumptions. My "novice"-tise runs out pretty quickly after basic orbital mechanics.

Comment: Your analysis is fundamentally correct.  The LHC uses whomping powerful magnets to guide and accelerate particles.  That principle wouldn't change due to size.  Further, a "star" that had sufficient gravity to pull into orbit and accelerate cosmic rays would likely be called a "black hole."